# MATLAB compiler says some functions in my app are using not licensed for compilation functions

Tags: matlab, compilation, compiler-warnings, dependency-management, matlab-compiler

I want to compile my app using [matlab-compiler](/questions/tagged/matlab-compiler) it does so, but with issues...
It says there are some functions that are not licensed for compilation.
The problem is that I haven't used those functions (one of them is `fimath.m`) in my app.
I think these functions are used inside some of my functions which I don't know.
My question is how to find out which one of my functions are using those functions in order to remove them or replace them with other functions.
There are more than 50 functions in my app and it's not possible to check them one by one.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe [Identifying program dependencies](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/identify-dependencies.html?requestedDomain=uk.mathworks.com) can help you?

Answer (score 0):

For every returned "unlicensed" function you can execute the following command,

```
dbstop in <function name> % without the <>
```

and afterwards run your code normally for several typical inputs/cases. If it stops at one of these breakpoints, look at the call stack (using either [`dbstack`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstack.html) or the Editor tab of the MATLAB GUI), and identify the entry point from your own code.

If none of the breakpoints is ever hit, it could mean that these functions are referred-to inside the code, but some logic is preventing their execution (turning them, practically, to "unreachable code"). In this case, you will likely need to remove these references manually. To know where from, using information from the link posted by [VTodorov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46971755/matlab-compiler-says-some-functions-in-my-app-are-using-not-licensed-for-compila#comment80890999_46971755) you can list the dependencies of each file using

```
[fList,pList] = matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts('myFun.m');
```

which can be called on the output of [`dir`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) (after some minor conversion). It could be useful to use the [`toponly` flag](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.codetools.requiredfilesandproducts.html#bt9at4d-1).